# What's the meaning of "Hardware drift"?

Tags: meaning

As in the title, please What's the meaning of "Hardware drift"? Is it hardware change in terms of configuration change?

Comment: Please provide some context—it likely means different things in different contexts, like so many other things do.

Comment: The context is actually the Microsoft one and I got the meaning thanks to the answer. Now, I wonder whether there are other context and would appreciate an example

Comment: It's when an old computer you're using for a boat anchor doesn't stay in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx),

> [t]he components that make up a device can change. This change is
>   referred to as ‘**hardware drift**’.

Windows apps can find out what kind of device they're running on by querying the device and getting back identifying information on the current hardware configuration.  Apps have to be careful when using this information because it can change as the apps run.  For example, unplugging a connected blue-tooth device will change that identifying information.  That change is one example of hardware drift.

A brief look through Google search results turns up a few references to "hardware drift" that apparently refer to calibration problems in electronic or hydraulic equipment.  But these references tend to be in advertisements for the equipment and tend to be older.  I think Microsoft has co-opted the phrase as a term of art.

Comment: Outside Microsoft context, it has no meaning in English?

Comment: I think it might have had a limited, specialized meaning in equipment calibration.  See my edit in the answer, but I think it's a Microsoft term of art now.  Did you have a particular context?